# Autofill input after selected select option Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want create some form with auto fill price on input box but i don't how to implemented to my code.
First i have select option then after select the option the price on the input box will generate automatically, then i'am input the discount value, then the total price will generate auto (basic price-discount %).
this my code:

```js
function bali() {
  var e = document.getElementById("bali");
  e.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var val = 7000000;
    document.getElementById("harga").value = val;
  })
};
```

```html
<form name="cal" action="">
  <table>
    <caption>
      <h1>
        Kalkulator
      </h1>
      <h3>
        Paket Wisata Imam Tour
      </h3>
    </caption>
    <tr>
      <td>Nama Paket Tour</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <select name="" id="paket">
          <option onchange="bali()" id="bali" value="">Paket Tour Bali</option>
          <option value="">Paket Tour Korea</option>
          <option value="">Paket Tour Eropa</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Harga Paket</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>Rp.<input id="harga" name="harga" type="number" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Diskon</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td><input id="diskon" name="diskon" type="number">%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Bayar</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td><input id="tot" name="tot" type="text"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding events wrong.
You can not add `addEventListener` change on `option` itself. It never changes. Select element does.

Move your `onchange` event to it.  `onchange="myFunction(event)"` and pass `event` into it.
Then you can fetch that event and selected option value:

```
function myFunction(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value)
```

Then you ca make conditions bsed on that :

```
if (event.target.value === "Bali") {
    document.getElementById("harga").value = 7000;
```

...

I added values into HTML as well to make it work.
Also i would suggest adding one default pres selected option:

```
  <option selected disabled>...</option>
```

This can be done may other ways also.

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value)

  if (event.target.value === "Bali") {
    document.getElementById("harga").value = 7000;
  } else if (event.target.value === "Korea") {
    document.getElementById("harga").value = 8000;
  } else if (event.target.value === "Eropa") {
    document.getElementById("harga").value = 9000;
  }

};
```

```html
<form name="cal" action="">
  <table>
    <caption>
      <h1>
        Kalkulator
      </h1>
      <h3>
        Paket Wisata Imam Tour
      </h3>
    </caption>
    <tr>
      <td>Nama Paket Tour</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <select name="" id="paket" onchange="myFunction(event)">
          <option selected disabled>...</option>
          <option value="Bali">Paket Tour Bali</option>
          <option value="Korea">Paket Tour Korea</option>
          <option value="Eropa">Paket Tour Eropa</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Harga Paket</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>Rp.<input id="harga" name="harga" type="number" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Diskon</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td><input id="diskon" name="diskon" type="number">%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Bayar</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td><input id="tot" name="tot" type="text"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you this perfect

Answer (score 0):

Put onchange in select, and pass the object as param, and you should also set ids and values for the options, such as:

```
<select name="" id="paket" onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <option id="bali" value="bali">Paket Tour Bali</option>
    <option id ="korea" value="korea">Paket Tour Korea</option>
    <option id ="eropa" value="eropa">Paket Tour Eropa</option>
</select>
```

Then, whenever the option changes, this function will be called

```
function myFunction(elem) {
    if (elem.value === "bali") {
        document.getElementById("harga").value = 700000;
    } else if(elem.value === "korea" {
       // put your korea logic here
    } else if (elem.value === "eropa") {
       // put your eropa logic here
    }
}
```